# Dev C in Windows 8: gcc Internal Error

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction, dev-c++

I am a teacher's assistant for a C programming class, and the instructor uses Dev C++ as the compiler for the class. Personally I would use a different one, but the choice is not mine here. Recently I installed the Windows 8 Professional 64 bit that is available on Dreamspark though my university, so I can start with some metro app development for some contests. Unfortunately, Dev C++ has stopped compiling. It previously worked fine with Windows 7 64 bit.

I get an error when compiling that reports back:

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Executing  gcc.exe...
gcc.exe "C:\Users\James\Documents\Homework\TA_CPRE_185\counter.c" -o "C:\Users\James\Documents\Homework\TA_CPRE_185\counter.exe"    -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include"   -L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib" 
gcc.exe: Internal error: Aborted (program collect2)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <URL:http://www.mingw.org/bugs.shtml> for instructions.

Execution terminated
Compilation successful
```

It says the compilation is successful but it is not, so no executable is made. I want to know if anyone has any ideas of what might get Dev C++ to work on this version of Windows, so I don't have to run Dev C++ in a virtual machine? I need it working, so I can do class demonstrations.

Comment: Is it just this one program (counter.c) or does it happen with any input ?

Comment: It is with every file I attempt to compile. Even a simple "helloWorld.c" file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is going to be a tough one. I'm going to assume you're using the MinGW/GCC installation that comes with Dev C++... it is pretty damn old. If you are desperate, you could try hooking in a newer MinGW, such as the TDM-GCC builds, but I have my doubts as to how well Dev-C++ will handle this.

Comment: Does Wwindows 8 have a compatibility function like XP mode?

Comment: It is the MinGW/GCC install, and the version he uses was copyrighted in 1991. I will see if I can figure out how to get it to use a newer compiler version. I wonder what the differences is between running it on this new Windows vs Windows 7...

Comment: I tried it in XP service pack 3 mode and I get the same error.

Comment: Got it to work!! ..can't answer my own question for 8 hours haha, but I installed a newer version of MinGW and changed all the directories to the new C:\MinGW\ corresponding locations in the "Compiler Options" selection under the "Tools" menu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that Dev-C++ comes with a very old version of MinGW (3.4.x if I'm not mistaken). MinGW versions before 4.2.2 will have problems compiling programs on Windows Vista and later unless they are on the PATH.

So you can either update your version of MinGW (as you mentioned in a comment that you have already done), or you can add the MinGW\bin directory to the system path.

Answer (score 18):

Please tell your teacher to update Dev-C++ instead:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/?source=directory

This one ships with a working MinGW 4.7 or a TDM-GCC 4.6.1 (x64) compiler, fixes endless amounts of bugs, and is also portable.

Comment: I felt inclined to flag this as advertisement, but instead I upvoted `:-)`.

Comment: [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior): *"Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you **must** disclose your affiliation in your answers."*

Answer (score 6):

If you cannot change your MINGW version, you can try to rename the following file : 
MinGW\libexec\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\collect2.exe to collect2.exe.old

(this solution worked after a migration from W7 to W10).

Comment: This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

I received the same error, but was able to get around it by doing the following.

1. Remove application using add/remove programs
2. Disable user access controls
3. Reboot
4. Download Dev-Cpp 5.4.0 TDM-GCC x64 4.7.1 Setup.exe
5. Right-click on downloaded file and change to "win7 compatability mode" for all users and select "run as administrator" and click "OK".
6. Right-click downloaded file and choose "run as an administrator" (note: this shouldn't be necessary, but it's windows so cover your bases)
7. Choose all the defaults, but on the last screen, deselect "run Dev C++ now" and then select "finish"
8. Open windows explorer and browse to the install directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp and locate "devcpp.exe"; right click and choose "win7 compatability mode" for all users and select "run as administrator" and click "OK" (again, this is probably not necessary, but it doesn't hurt anything either).
9. Double-click the application and pin to your taskbar for ease of use.
10. Open a new project and test it out, it should work w/o issue.

Answer (score 1):

I used [MinGW Installation Manager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/?source=typ_redirect) to download the last version of C Compiler (5.3.0-3 at this moment) and I repliced the files in the folder of Dev-Cpp. Now, its working perfectly in my Windows 10.