# Source file not compiled Dev C++

Tags: c, dev-c++

I just installed Dev C++ and I am learning C programming.
the code i used was

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main()
{
  printf("Hello world");
  getch();
}
```

I saved it as a .c file. When I compile it works fine, but when I compile and run it says source file not compiled. So I googled buncha things and came across this video on youtube which shows you how to fix it. I also saw other forums on google which suggest the same thing... However, after doing whats asked, Now I can't even compile my code. I get this error

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Executing  C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\gcc.exe...
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\gcc.exe "C:\Users\ubaid\Documents\C\Untitled1.c" -o "C:\Users\ubaid\Documents\C\Untitled1.exe"    -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include"   -L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib" 
gcc.exe: Internal error: Aborted (program collect2)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <URL:http://www.mingw.org/bugs.shtml> for instructions.

Execution terminated
```

I have also used what is asked on this link, and still no luck.. 
http://learntogeek.com/miscellaneous/solved-source-file-not-compiled-error-in-dev-cpp/

I am using windows 8

Comment: Does your source file actually include those quotation marks?

Comment: I cannot piece together enough concrete details from this. Please use full sentences with full words, capital letters, verbatim code... Your code and compilation commands are all about C, but you tagged the question C++. What is going on here?

Comment: Duplicate? [Dev C in Windows 8: gcc Internal Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811762/dev-c-in-windows-8-gcc-internal-error)

Comment: Can you try to do it manually and tell me what the error is? gcc -o hello hello.c (or whatever your file is named)

Comment: If none works, You can try the new DEVC++ from here. https://www.bloodshed.net/

Answer (score 19):

I was having this issue and fixed it by going to:
C:\Dev-Cpp\libexec\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2
, then deleting collect2.exe

Comment: worked .. but why is it there if it isn't necessary?

Comment: oh god. you really should not delete MinGW binaries. it can mess up a lot of things.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of deleting "collect2.exe", you can rename it, so that you can rename it back to its original name when it becomes necessary. Peace!

Comment: This is not supposed to be an answer. You should not delete compiler binaries, they are not unnecessary. Better don't use Dev C++, it is obsolete.

Answer (score 12):

Install new version of Dev c++. It works fine in Windows 8. It also supports 64 bit version.

Download link is http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/ .

Comment: There are a number of better IDEs out there since the dark days of Bloodshed Dev-C++. Qt Creator (even for non-Qt projects!) is at the top of my list, followed by a good text editor + commandline.

Comment: This was a good answer to me, I was just trying to use a version that was not for my SO. Windows 10 working well with the newest versions.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're using windows 7 with the [Orwell Dev CPP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/)

This version of Dev CPP is good for windows 8 only. However on Windows 7 you need the older version of it which is [devcpp-4.9.9.2_setup.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dev-cpp/files/Binaries/Dev-C++%204.9.9.2/)
Download it from the link and use it.
(Don't forget to uninstall any other version already installed on your pc)
Also note that the older version does not work with windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

This maybe because the c compiler is designed to work in linux.I had this problem too and to fix it go to `tools` and select `compiler options`.In the box click on `programs`

Now you will see a tab with `gcc` and `make` and the respective path to it.Edit the `gcc` and `make` path to use `mingw32-c++.exe` and `mingw32-make.exe` respectively.Now it will work.

[image: The Answer]

The reason was that you were using compilers built for linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try doing it manually from the command prompt.  Navigate to the path of the file and type:

```
gcc filename.c -o filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Please follow the following steps:

1. Right Click the My comp. Icon
2. Click Advanced Setting.
3. CLick Environment Variable. On the top part of Environment Variable Click New
4. Set Variable name as: PATH then 
   Set Variable Value as: (" the location of g++ .exe" ) 
   For ex. C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin
5. Click OK

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because your settings are not correct.

For example I receive

> ```
> cannot open output file Project1.exe: Permission denied
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> mingw32-make.exe: *** [Project1.exe] Error 1
> ```

Because I have no permission to write on my `exe` file.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, and with Dr.Topaz's help, I have learned that you will want to confirm that the program set for `g++` in the Compiler Options really does compile the source code. In my case, the `C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\g++.exe` program did *not* create an exe, but the `C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\c++.exe` program did. Either program appears to be intended to take the same arguments and options as [GNU g++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/). I would love to find an actual doc on the Dev-C++ compiler programs, but I have not so far.

You can test the compiler program with a simple example like this:

```
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\c++.exe hello.cpp -o hello.exe
```

Currently in 2021, the [Dev-C++](http://www.dev-cpp.com/) site invites you to download either original Dev-C++ or a newer fork by a group named Embarcadero.

I decided to try the Embarcadero version and the experience was slightly better. The UI is still a tad dated, but the `g++.exe` program it came with was able to compile programs without issue. Again, take note of where the program is being installed, but in my case, the Embarcadero compiler programs were in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Dev-Cpp\TDM-GCC-64\bin`.

Both original Dev-C++ and Embarcadero come with mingw-32 versions of the compiler programs that from what I see do work in a Git Bash console, with slight differences such as not recognizing a default locale when using the command `std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""))`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this similar error, and none of the solutions worked.
so I tried to download the latest version from here, https://www.bloodshed.net/

[image: thisone]

I rerun the program.
and everything is now working correctly.

Answer (score -2):

I was facing the same issue as described above.

It can be resolved by creating a new project and creating a new file in that project.
Save the file and then try to build and run.

Hope that helps. :)