# Dev c++ 4.9.9.2 is installed on my windows 8.1. Warning: "Source file not compiled"

Tags: c, dev-c++

This is my hello world program. It compiles, but when I Run it says :

> "Source file not compiled"

I have included header files `stdio.h` and `conio.h`. 
Any solution.? I installed code::blocks as well, I got a similar error in that IDE as well.

```
int main()
{
   printf("Hello world");
   return 0;
}
```

As it compiles, it is generating an exe file, which is not showing up in command prompt, it is somehow getting deleted(may be McAfee is doing it)

Comment: May we know how did you compile it?

Comment: using 'compile' option in the IDE.

Comment: It looks duplicate. Please take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514682/source-file-not-compiled-dev-c).

Comment: Well, I saw it , I tried options like setting PATH variable, installing code::blocks . . nothing worked

Comment: run the program as administrator. Administrative privilege to create file in c drive may be  the issue.

Comment: Well, my user account is admin account.

Comment: Please try to run as administrator, even if your current user is admin. Sometimes the result is different.

Comment: The generated exe file is getting deleted. McAfee is deleting the file i suppose. That is why it is saying 'source file not compiled'

Answer (score 0):

Specify path into the path variable...u can get your path variable into control panel ...if ur file successfully compiled ...means there is no error ..OK ...then if u run ur program then ur CPP file path should be set into path variable same like as java..

Comment: I tried setting the path to bin folder, but same error. PATH = C:\Dev-Cpp\bin

Answer (score 0):

Are you making a `C` or `C++` program? Include a header file that references `iostream` also.

Comment: I have seen some of your posts, try making proper sentences without text message slang like `U r`, instead write `You are` and stop with all the `....` a sentence stops with a single dot. The SE community likes clean and clear answers on clean and clear questions.