# I am trying to add a header file into another header file

Tags: c

I am trying to add a header file into another header file but it says "Source file not compiled"
Is there something wrong with what I am trying to do?

```
#include "\\Mac\Home\Desktop\BSD 2017\Study\BTP100SCC.05062.2177 Programming Fundamentals Using C\BTP-Project\A1\MS2\contacts.h"

struct Name
 {
    char firstName[31];
    char middleInitial[7];
    char lastName[36];

};
```

Comment: Please add your code, so we can help you.

Comment: Can you let us know if the code is complied. If it is still compiled and you are getting the same error delete the output executable and compile it again.

Comment: check here to see if it solves your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514682/source-file-not-compiled-dev-c

Comment: You shouldn't use such a long header path in your code.  The location should be specified on the command line (`-I` option on Unix), and either `"contacts.h"` or perhaps `"MS2/contacts.h"` in the code.  Using backslashes vs slashes suggests you're on Windows.  Be cautious.  Slashes normally work as well as backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer for a short question. No `#include "file.h"` should work fine.

"Source file not compiled" indicates that you may not have compiled your source file. Have you run a command such as `% gcc -c file.c`?

**edit: listing your full directory each time is bad practice. Use the -I option to specify the directory search path

If you have not done this, then you should read up on [how to compile a c program](http://ce.uml.edu/compile.htm).

Note: If you run windows you may need to use a Unix command-line environment such as [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html)