# What does this message mean?

Tags: c, mingw

I am using code blocks for C programming , my problem is when i run the program i have made , i get this statement in the build log.

-------------- Build: Debug in C assignment (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

```
mingw32-g++.exe  -o "bin\Debug\C assignment.exe" obj\Debug\main.o    
mingw32-g++.exe: Internal error: Aborted (program collect2)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <URL:http://www.mingw.org/bugs.shtml> for instructions.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
```

What does this mean ? I have output statments in my program , but i don't get the desired output, instead i get the above message in the build log.
 By the way am new to C language and also this is my first time using the code blocks IDE.

EDIT:-

This is my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct preparation_time{
int spongecake;
int meringue;
int chocalate;
int red_velvet;
};

void cake_order(struct preparation_time *);



main()
{

struct preparation_time caketime;

cake_order(&caketime);


}


void cake_order(struct preparation_time *thetime)
{
    int i;

    thetime->chocalate=25;
    thetime->meringue=45;
    thetime->red_velvet=60;
    thetime->spongecake=30;

     for(i=0;i<180;i++)
    {

        if(thetime->chocalate==i)
        {
            printf("Chocalate cake");
            thetime->chocalate=thetime->chocalate*2;

        }
    if(thetime->spongecake==i)
    {
        printf("Sponge cake");
        thetime->spongecake=thetime->spongecake*2;
    }

    if(thetime->meringue==i)
    {
        printf("Meringue");
        thetime->meringue=thetime->meringue*2;

    }

    if(thetime->red_velvet==i)
    {

        printf("Red velvet");
        thetime->red_velvet=thetime->red_velvet*2;
    }

}

}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The message looks like you've hit a bug in the compiler or build system.

Comment: Try replacing the backslashes in your filenames with forward-slashes, e.g. `mingw32-++.exe -o "bin/Debug/C assignment.exe" obj/Debug/Main.o`

Comment: I tried the same program in another computer and it worked. Seems like a bug in the compiler. 

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @Dai. MinGW gcc handles backslashes in filenames just fine.

Comment: mingw32-g++.exe: Internal error: means it is a bug in the compiler, you should upgrade if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dev C in Windows 8: gcc Internal Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811762/dev-c-in-windows-8-gcc-internal-error)

Comment: The exact same program name as well, what are the odds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `main` should `return 0;`. Also for good style you should declare it explicitly as `int main`.

Then (i tried) there are **no** warnings when compiling and the program runs fine.

The most likely problem is that there is a problem with the command-line path: backslashes, spaces, upper/lowercase.

- First try moving `obj\Debug\main.o` in front of the -o.
- Try replacing backslashes by forwardslashes.
- If that didn't work try to use only directories that have no whitespaces, uppercase or special characters.
- If that didn't work, experiment: place everything in one directory and only using filenames, no paths.

The less likely problem is that this is an actual (MinGW-)GCC compiler bug, in which case you should first **update** your compiler and **retry**. If it still fails then actually submit as it asks.

Good luck!

Comment: main implicitly returns 0, no requirement to have a return statement in there.

Comment: @rubenvb in C++. but not in C.

Comment: C99 `5.1.2.2.3`: "If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value returned by the main function as its argument; **reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0**. If the return type is not compatible with int, the termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified."

Comment: @rubenvb do you see a `-std=c99` in his command line? It would be no reason to `-1`, because it is a minor point anyway (as i wrote it is only for "good style") and my answer contains many other points too.