# Source file not compiled, even after compilation process is complete

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++

I have installed Dev C++ on Windows 8 and this is my first program, however it runs smoothly until I run it.

Here is my first program:

[image: The first program]

When I compile it...

[image: Compilation]

When I run it however, here arises the problem...

[image: Error in running the program]

However the Compiler Log shows this message:

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Executing  gcc.exe...
gcc.exe "C:\Users\Zainab\Downloads\Table.c (2).c" -o "C:\Users\Zainab\Downloads\Table.c     (2).exe"    -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include"   -L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib" 
gcc.exe: Internal error: Aborted (program collect2)
Please submit a full bug report.
```

CODE:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c=1;

    printf("Enter the table of:");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter the number of times:");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    while (c <= b) {
        printf("%d", a);
        printf("* %d", c);
        printf("= %d", a*c);

        if (c < b) {
            printf("\n");
        }

        c++;
    }

    return 0;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Dev-C++ ?!? Can you use something more recent, like Code::Blocks ?

Comment: Maybe check that "Log" button to see an actual compiler error?

Comment: Please put your actual code here. Not a printscreen.

Comment: Dev-C++ has been abandoned for years. Please use something more recent like Code::Blocks.

Comment: @OP: See the `info` section of the tag `dev-c++` to find some alternatives to Dev-C++.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dev-c%2b%2b/info

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dev C in Windows 8: gcc Internal Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811762/dev-c-in-windows-8-gcc-internal-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use better tools.
Dev-C++ has been abandoned.
A good free open source C++ IDE is CodeBlocks.
There are others e.g. Orwell Dev-C++

Comment: Orwell Orwell Dev-C++ is not Dev-C++. Added your ide.